# How to config the v-list-item width to avoid ellipsis

Tags: vuetify.js

I create a card with some items inside but i cannot change the width of the v-list-items.
When two v-list-items are on same line the length is 50% for each and i need that the left one be wider.
I made one codepen to show my problem (maybe the problem is how i create the items).
If the left item is wider the ellipsis in the text (long text but not so much as for ellipsis) is not necessary.

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/wolverine4277/pen/qBbJpdm)

```
<v-list-item-content class="pt-0">
  <v-list-item-title>long text but not so much as for ellipsis</v-list-item-title>
  <v-list-item-subtitle>Today</v-list-item-subtitle>
</v-list-item-content>
<v-list-item-content class="pt-0">
  <v-list-item-title align="right" class="font-weight-light display-2">180</v-list-item-title>
  <v-list-item-subtitle align="right">&nbsp;</v-list-item-subtitle>
</v-list-item-content>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put your `<v-list-item-content>` inside a `<div class="myDiv">` for example and set your desired width or other styles to that class.

Comment: Thanks @M3HDI, the div one is pretty simple. I was complicating myself trying to do it with pure Vuetify!

Comment: Still, you could simply put a line style in  v-list-item-title                                                 <v-list-item-title style="white-space: normal;"> ITEM_TITLE </v-list-item-title>
this way you can keep v-list-item vuetify style like font and text aligment.

Comment: yeah a wrapper div will get it done though I was hoping for a flex / width config